# Can PARI compute class numbers without factoring the discriminant?

Tags: nt.number-theory, computational-number-theory, computer-algebra, sage

When calculating properties of algebraic number fields, one of the hardest steps is factorizing the discriminant of a defining polynomial. This is necessary in the Pohst-Zassenhaus algorithm for calculating the maximal order (cf. [Cohen], Alg. 6.1.8).

On the other hand, we often happen to know (through theoretical means or at least empirical observations) at which primes the order needs to be maximized. In PARI, it is possible to pass such a list of primes to the `nfinit` function. The `bnfinit` function for "Buchmann number fields", i. e. for the computation of class groups and fundamental units, however, does not seem to know this option. In Sage, it is possible to write `pari('bnfinit')(nf_instance)`, but it is unclear to me whether this only extracts the defining polynomial from the `nf_instance` and recomputes the remaining data or whether this really circumvents the recomputation of the maximal order.

In PARI's class group algorithm ([Cohen], Alg. 6.5.6), it becomes necessary in Step 10 to identify the ramified primes in the factor basis. However, according to my understanding, this only requires divisibility tests, not knowledge of the full factorization of the discriminant, and even if it did, results that do not depend on knowledge of the factorization but have to be dealt with critically could be worthwhile.

*Is it possible in PARI or any other computer algebra system to calculate class numbers without the need to factorize the (field or polynomial) discriminant, if the maximal order is known?*

[Cohen]: Cohen, Henri: A Course in Computational Algebraic Number Theory. Springer 1993.

PARI documentation: [nfinit](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/General_number_fields.html#se:nfinit), [bnfinit](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html/General_number_fields.html#se:bnfinit)

Comment: Yes, simply do bnfinit(nf) where nf was computed with nfinit with options avoiding factorisation of the discriminant. I don't know how Sage handles this.